# Run a bash script in Xcode only when "Build & Run"

Tags: xcode, bash, scripting, build

Is there a way, in Xcode, to run a bash script in a build phase, only when I "Build & Run" and not in all other occasions?

Actually, what I would like to do, is to write a script to update the build number every time I build and run a new version on the device.

Comment: Only when you Build & Run, or also when you just run?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. 'Build & Run' as opposed to what, exactly? Just 'Build'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode does not tell your script why it's building — that is, if it's going to run the app afterwards or not —; only that it *is* building. Also note that selecting 'Run' as opposed to 'Build & Run' does **not** run scripts in Run Script phases.

If you build in other occasions, you can pass build settings to `xcodebuild` (if building from the command line) or by selecting a different build configuration (if building from the Xcode application), which you can refer to in your build scripts as environment variables. For example:

```
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
    # increment build number
fi
```

(This script uses the `CONFIGURATION` built-in build setting, but you can create custom build settings if needed.)